# Do I understand Maven correctly?

Tags: java, maven

Recently I wanted to try the Apache Crunch library. For this purpose I learned about Maven.

To my understanding, in order to use a library one simply needs to add to the project's `pom.xml` file the appropriate `<dependency>..</dependency>` block, and build the project. All of the dependencies will be downloaded recursively by Maven.

My question is simply: is my understanding correct? Because in this example, I simply pasted the `crunch-core` dependency in the `pom` file, and only some of the dependencies were downloaded (thus I got `ClassNotFoundException`s when running the application, which is what I want to avoid).

My question isn't related specifically to Crunch. I'm trying to verify if my understanding of how to use a third-party library using Maven is correct. Or if I'm missing something.

EDIT: I see my understanding is correct. Regarding my specific problem, here's my `pom`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>aviv</groupId>
    <artifactId>crunch-try</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.crunch</groupId>
            <artifactId>crunch-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0-hadoop2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Any guess why the app fails? Am I expected to download additional dependencies separately?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Comment: So what could be the reason running the app fails?

Comment: We can't guess. Edit your question and post your pom. Roughy, either the crunch people published a defective artifact, or it has intentionally 'optional' dependencies that require you to fill in the blanks.

Comment: @AvivCohn, perhaps you need jars that aren't in the core package. Can you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: You might want to add some examples of the missing classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several of crunch-core's dependencies are marked 'provided'. This means that the crunch developers expect it to be used only in an environment where someone or something adds them to the classpath for you. You need to either run your app in the intended environment, or make manually add all those provided dependencies to your pom.

The only reason that provided dependencies are in the pom at all is that Maven does not (yet) distinguish between 'the content of the pom needed to build the thing' and 'the content of the pom that enables other things to use it.' Maven does not download these because the original author is saying, 'this jar needs to run inside hadoop, and these things are already in the classpath of hadoop.'

I read them at [this convenient location](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.crunch%7Ccrunch-core%7C0.12.0-hadoop2%7Cjar).

Comment: And these aren't downloaded by Maven? If so, why are they listed in the POM?

Comment: I see. What I did is simply paste the entire POM you shared, but deleted the `<scope>provided</scope>` lines. It doesn't work, complaining I didn't specify the `version` of the dependencies. Is there a way to tell Maven "just get the most recent version"?

Comment: Don't do any of this. Run your code in hadoop or it won't work. See https://crunch.apache.org/getting-started.html.

Comment: If I include all the dependencies, why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Because it depends on the entire Hadoop ecosystem _running_, not just on some things being in your classpath.

Comment: Do you have experience with Crunch? It has a `MemPipeline` class designed to run programs in the desktop RAM. So it seems weird I'd need to run it in the Hadoop cluster just to experiment.

Comment: From Getting Started: "MemPipeline: Executes a pipeline in-memory on the client."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83051/discussion-between-bmargulies-and-aviv-cohn).